# Issue with resetting theorem counter

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am using LyX to typeset a document. I wanted to use another theorem-like construct not available in `amsthm`. So I included it using LaTeX code.

```
\newtheorem{discussion}{Discussion}[section]
```

This works fine except the next theorem that appears using the built in theorem construct ends up having the same number as the one above. I tried using `\stepcounter` and `\addtocounter`, but this does not change the numbering.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: There is *no* built-in theorem construct, unless it's LyX that provides one.

Comment: @egreg: By "built-in" I meant "available in amsthm". I might be using incorrect  terminology, but I don't think what I mean is ambiguous.

Comment: @henrique: I had read about the MWE, but as I said I am using LyX to do this, so I am not sure how I can provide an MWE for that. If I export to latex and try to compile, I end up getting a bunch of errors which are not representative of my situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this new structure to share the counter of a previously defined theorem-like environment, you can use the first optional argument of `\newtheorem` to indicate the counter dependance; for example:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{discussion}[theorem]{Discussion}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I had initially. This did not work for me either. Perhaps it's the way LyX interacts with latex code.

Comment: @Zoey Then, we'll need to see a minimal, complete example of your actual code showing the settings relevant for this issue. Please add this minimal version to your question.

Comment: I am using LyX to do this, so I am not sure how I can provide an MWE for that. If I export to latex and try to compile, I end up getting a bunch of errors which are not representative of my situation.

Comment: @Zoey: and I have no idea about LyX; anyway, build in LyX a document as short as possible illustrating the problem and then export it to LaTeX, and upload it somewhere. Add the link to your original question so someone can take a look at it and see if the problem can be found.